# NetStream.seek in "Data Generation Mode"

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netstream

I created a flv player using the method NetStream.appendBytes for entering data into the buffer.
For now, I perform the seek action in this way:

ns.seek (0);
ns.appendBytesAction (NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_SEEK);
ns.appendBytes (seekPosBytes);

[Like I've read here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2845527)

I perform a seek(number) (which from what I've understood flushes the buffer) and beginning to incorporate the new bytes (those related to the position from which I start to play).
This means that even if the entire video is loaded, the buffer is emptied and everything has to be reloaded.
It is possible to seek using the data already loaded into the buffer using the method NetStream.appendBytes?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the netstream's [inbufferseek](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#inBufferSeek) property to true?